# POST request in android with OnClick listview

Tags: java, android, node.js, express

### I am trying to dynamically pass the data to next activity by making a post request to server

---

**My Analysis::**

- I am not able to determine whether the error is on server on express or the android client
  code

**Or**

- Whether i am making a proper post request to server in Async task

---

**[Note]**

Data from **`Url`** variable is displaying in the list view
But
Onclick of listrow .... where a post request need to be made to server and a JSON response had to be retrieved is the place where error is appearing

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7003/";

    private static String url1 = "http://54.218.73.244:7003/RestaurantDesc/";



    String item;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> TimeMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instantiating ProgressDialog with onCreate method
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();

    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait", true, false);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String _response = null;
            try
            {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response =EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
            JSONArray first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
            JSONArray second_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RestaurantTimings");
             for(int i=0;i<first_array.length();i++)
             {
                    JSONObject c = second_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item = new Item();

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    int id = c.getInt("_id");
                    String TIME = c.getString("RestaurantTime");
                    item.setTime(TIME);

                    c = first_array.getJSONObject(i);

                    String NAME=c.getString("restaurantNAME");
                    item.setName(NAME);

                    String URL=c.getString("url");
                    item.setUrl(URL);


                    yourData.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            TextView timedisplay=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.RestaurantTimeID);


            ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
            ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
            yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    item = yourData.get(position).getName();


                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url1);

                    try {
                        // Add your data
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key", item));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }


                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RestaurantDesc.class);
                    i.putExtra("key", url1);
                    i.putExtra("CC_RES",item.toString());
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

**Part of Express code on server::**

```
app.get('/RestaurantDesc/:Key',function(request,response,next){

    var keyName=request.params.Key;
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;

    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM ', keyName, function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        name_of_restaurants = rows;
                        callback();
                });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM ', RestaurantTimings, function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    RestaurantTimings = rows;
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'restaurants' : name_of_restaurants,
        'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
    });
} );
} );
```

**[LOG]**

```
08-29 08:20:01.963: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=6: spin on suspend #1 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
08-29 08:20:01.963: D/dalvikvm(333): Temporarily moving tid 342 to fg (was 0)
08-29 08:20:01.963: D/dalvikvm(333): Temporarily raised priority on tid 342 (10 -> 0)
08-29 08:20:02.041: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=6: spin on suspend resolved in 1081 msec
08-29 08:20:02.041: D/dalvikvm(333): Restored policy of 342 to 0
08-29 08:20:02.041: D/dalvikvm(333): Restored priority on 342 to 10
08-29 08:20:12.541: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 177K, 48% free 3078K/5895K, external 2111K/2137K, paused 86ms
08-29 08:20:18.042: W/System.err(333): org.json.JSONException: Value Cannot of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-29 08:20:18.042: W/System.err(333):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
08-29 08:20:18.062: W/System.err(333):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
08-29 08:20:18.062: W/System.err(333):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
08-29 08:20:18.062: W/System.err(333):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:114)
08-29 08:20:18.062: W/System.err(333):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-29 08:20:18.072: W/System.err(333):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-29 08:20:18.072: W/System.err(333):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-29 08:20:18.072: W/System.err(333):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-29 08:20:18.072: W/System.err(333):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-29 08:20:18.072: W/System.err(333):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-29 08:20:18.082: W/System.err(333):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-29 08:20:18.082: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
08-29 08:20:18.082: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:138)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-29 08:20:18.112: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 08:25:02.411: I/Process(333): Sending signal. PID: 333 SIG: 9
08-29 08:25:49.932: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 178K, 48% free 3078K/5895K, external 2111K/2137K, paused 88ms
08-29 08:25:51.571: W/System.err(364): org.json.JSONException: Value Cannot of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-29 08:25:51.701: W/System.err(364):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
08-29 08:25:51.862: W/System.err(364):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
08-29 08:25:51.941: W/System.err(364):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
08-29 08:25:52.043: W/System.err(364):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:114)
08-29 08:25:52.081: W/System.err(364):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-29 08:25:52.081: W/System.err(364):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-29 08:25:52.171: W/System.err(364):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-29 08:25:52.231: W/System.err(364):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-29 08:25:52.251: W/System.err(364):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-29 08:25:52.261: W/System.err(364):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-29 08:25:52.301: W/System.err(364):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-29 08:25:52.331: D/AndroidRuntime(364): Shutting down VM
08-29 08:25:52.331: W/dalvikvm(364): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:138)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-29 08:25:52.361: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 08:26:12.072: I/Process(364): Sending signal. PID: 364 SIG: 9
08-29 08:26:38.353: D/dalvikvm(396): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 179K, 48% free 3078K/5895K, external 2111K/2137K, paused 88ms
08-29 08:26:40.043: W/System.err(396): org.json.JSONException: Value Cannot of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-29 08:26:40.353: W/System.err(396):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:114)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.doInBackground(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-29 08:26:40.562: W/System.err(396):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-29 08:26:40.571: W/System.err(396):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-29 08:26:40.571: W/System.err(396):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-29 08:26:40.633: D/AndroidRuntime(396): Shutting down VM
08-29 08:26:40.633: W/dalvikvm(396): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:138)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc$ParsingAsync.onPostExecute(RestaurantDesc.java:1)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-29 08:26:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Hope i am clear**

*Thanks*

Comment: Take a closer look at the "org.json.JSONException: Value Cannot of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject", somewhere you're trying to create a JSONObject for something that's actually a String.

Comment: Thanks, but the POST request i have done, .... Is that correct ... Imean have i followed proper steps in placing functions in proper place ?

Comment: It looks fine, and the logcat clearly shows that the error is in parsing the feed. You can print the response string just to make sure that it is in order.